# How to catch exceptions when using Lombok's @Cleanup?

Tags: java, resources, lombok

I am using [Lombok's @Cleanup](http://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup.html) and even when I find it very useful, I cannot figure out how can I catch an exception being thrown by the main block of code that makes use of the resource to be cleant.

My code is the following:

```
ScriptRunner runner = null;
try {
    runner = scriptRunner();

    for (Resource sqlFile : sqlScripts) {
        runScript(sqlFile.getFile(), runner);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Error found when attempting to run script", ex);
} finally {
    if (runner != null) {
        runner.closeConnection();
    }
}
```

With Lombok, I could simplify the code above this way:

```
@Cleanup("closeConnection") ScriptRunner runner = scriptRunner();

for (Resource sqlFile : sqlScripts) {
    runScript(sqlFile.getFile(), runner);
}
```

But I would be missing the possibility of catching any exception that might arise when the for loop executes. Is there any way to do this in an elegant way with Lombok? (i.e. other than programmatically using "try /catch?)

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you want to process the exception you need to catch it, and for that you'll need a try-catch block.

Full Disclosure: I am one of the [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org) developers.

Comment: Where does the try-catch block need to go? Around the whole block from the @Cleanup annotation to the end of the scope? Or a more limited scope?

Comment: I would use the smallest scope possible.

Comment: I believe that Lombok will add a try {...} finally{} block anyway, regardless of where one puts the try/catch block, so, my conclusion is that, in this case, it's much cleaner not to use Lombok since the verbosity of the two options is pretty much the same. Thanks Roel for your answer.

Comment: I really like the @Cleanup idea but without the ability to catch and handle any throws, I don't see it as being that useful.